# LoadError: libgvc.so.5: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory - RMagick2.so

Tags: imagemagick, ubuntu-14.04, rmagick

Recently I switched our tests from ubuntu 12 to ubuntu 14.04 worker on Solano. Now when I run `bundle exec rake` in the debug console I get

```
rake aborted!
LoadError: libgvc.so.5: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory - /home/u261/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/rmagick-2.16.0/lib/RMagick2.so
/home/u261/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:292:in `require'
/home/u261/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:292:in `block in require'
/home/u261/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:258:in `load_dependency'
/home/u261/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:292:in `require'
/home/u261/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/rmagick-2.16.0/lib/rmagick_internal.rb:12:in `<top (required)>'
/home/u261/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:292:in `require'
/home/u261/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:292:in `block in require'
/home/u261/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:258:in `load_dependency'
/home/u261/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:292:in `require'
/home/u261/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/rmagick-2.16.0/lib/rmagick.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
/home/u261/src/repo/app`enter code here`/config/application.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
/home/u261/src/repo/app/Rakefile:5:in `require'
/home/u261/src/repo/app/Rakefile:5:in `<top (required)>'
/home/u261/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/rake-12.3.1/exe/rake:27:in `<top (required)>'
/home/u261/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/bin/bundle:23:in `load'
/home/u261/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/bin/bundle:23:in `<main>'
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

I use rmagick version 2.16.0. In our `solano.yml` pre-setup hook looks the following way:

```
hooks:
  early:
    # Install ImageMagick
    sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get -y install imagemagick libmagickwand-dev
```

I searched for `libgvc.so.5` on the box with `sudo find / -name "libgvc*"` but I could not find it

Any thoughts?

**UPDATE 1**

Searching the gems for libgvc gives me

```
ag "libgvc" /home/u261/bundle/ruby

/home/u261/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.4.0/rmagick-2.16.0/mkmf.log
warning: libgvc.so.5, needed by /usr/local/lib/libMagickCore-6.Q16.so, not found (try using -rpath or -rpath-link)
```

**UPDATE 2**

`identify -version` outputs

```
identify: error while loading shared libraries: libgvc.so.5: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```